# Do positive almost periodic functions whose mean values converge to 0 also converge to 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_{n}\}, f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ be an infinite sequence of almost periodic functions, and let the sequence of their mean values $M\{f_{n}\}$ converge to $0$. Does then $\{f_{n}\}$ converge to the zero function $f(x)=0$,$x\in\mathbb{R}$?

If this is not true in general, what additional conditions must $\{f_{n}\}$ satisfy in order to converge to the zero function?

It is known that an almost periodic function $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is the zero function if $M\{g\} = 0$.

Is there any literature treating this question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g\geq 0$ be almost periodic and different from the zero function, then $M(g)>0$. This can be found in "Katznelson Y., Introduction to Harmonic Analysis", p. 177.

However, if you have a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of non-negative almost periodic function converging in mean to zero, then $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge pointwise to the zero function. Define

$$ h_n: [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, 
h_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1 - n\vert x \vert + 1/n,& x\in [-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}],\\
1/n,& \text{else.} \end{cases}$$

Let $f_n$ be the periodic extension of $h_n$. On computes

$$ M(f_n)= \int_{0}^{1/n} 1 - n\vert x \vert + 1/n \  dx = \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \rightarrow 0.$$

But, $f_n(0)=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and thus $f_n$ does not converge pointwise to the zero function.